# Modify the x and y axis to reduce the gap between the values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a sns plot using the below code.

```
fig=sns.lineplot(data=zrrgroupby,x='filedate',y='ResourceName',hue='location')
```

The filedate which is the x asis has data for every monday in a month. Is it possible to have some sort of identifier or a smaller grid to denote it?

Similarly the y axis is the `ResourceName` which is nothingbut `ResourceCount`. Can  I break it down into smaller sections?

Current output:
[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

The lines between 2 months denote the Monday's that occur in that month as the data is generated every monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridlines are draw at the positions of the ticks of both axes. There are two levels of ticks: major (which usually have a label) and minor (in between).

For the horizontal gridlines, secondary ticks can be placed with multiples of 10. For the vertical gridlines, a secondary tick for every monday can be placed. Note that secondary ticks are suppressed when they coincide with a major tick.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.dates import MO, WeekdayLocator
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sns.set()
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
dates = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-07-01', freq='D')
N = len(dates)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.repeat(dates, 2),
                   'Resource': np.random.uniform(-3, 3.1, 2 * N).cumsum() + np.tile([50, 130], N),
                   'Location': np.tile(['loc A', 'loc B'], N)})
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Resource', hue='Location')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(MO)))
ax.grid(True, which='major', lw=1, color='darkgrey')
ax.grid(True, which='minor', lw=1, ls=':', color='darkgrey')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]